# How to have template and non-template functions in one file

Tags: c++, templates

I have a utility file with a template function and an 'ordinary' function:

```
#ifndef __UTILS_CPP__
#define __UTILS_CPP__

#include <stdlib.h>

template<typename T> int makeIntN(const T V) { return (int)V;}

int makeIntS(const char *pVal) { return atoi(pVal);}

#endif
```

These functions are used by two other classes, subA and subB.

***SubA.h***:

```
#ifndef __SUBA_H__
#define __SUBA_H__

class SubA {
public:
    SubA() {};
    static int actionN(int i);
    int actionS(const char *p);    
};    
#endif
```

***SubA.cpp***:

```
#include "suba.h"
#include "utils.cpp"

int SubA::actionN(int i) {
    return makeIntN(i);
}

int SubA::actionS(const char *p) {
    return makeIntS(p);
}
```

***SubC.h***

```
#ifndef __SUBC_H__
#define __SUBC_H__

class SubC {
public:
    SubC() {};
    int actionN(float f);
    static int actionS(const char *p);
};    

#endif
```

***SubC.cpp***

```
#include "subc.h"
#include "utils.cpp"

int SubC::actionS(const char *p) {
    return makeIntS(p);
}

int SubC::actionN(float f) {
    return makeIntN(f);
}
```

In main(), i create instances of these classes and call some of their methods:

***cltest.cpp***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "suba.h"
#include "subc.h"

int main() {
    int iResult = -1;

    SubA *psa = new SubA();
    iResult = psa->actionN(17);
    printf("Res A: %d\n", iResult);
    iResult = psa->actionS("17");
    printf("Res A: %d\n", iResult);
    SubC *psc = new SubC();
    iResult = psc->actionN(17.65);
    printf("Res C: %d\n", iResult);

    return iResult;
}
```

When i compile this like this:`g++ clstest.cpp subc.cpp suba.cpp`, i obviously get an error because  makeIntS() is included each by SubA and SubC.

I tried various ways of `#include`s and different ways to link, but either `makeIntN()` is undefined or else `makeIntS()` is muitply defined.

How can i get this to compile & link without splitting up the utils file into a template part and a non-template part?

Comment: Try `inline`ing the free non-template function

Comment: Unrelated: `#define__UTILS_CPP__` some identifiers are reserved for the implementation, including the one starting with two underscores and the one starting with an underscore immediatly followed by a uppercase letter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define (non-method) functions in header libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568807/how-to-define-non-method-functions-in-header-libraries)

Comment: NEVER include a *.cpp file. Just put it all in a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways of having a non-template free function defined in a header file:

- make a function `inline`
- make a function `static`
- place function in anonymous namespace

I suggest you to go for making a `int makeIntS(const char *pVal);` function `inline`.

Comment: Making makeIntS()  either static or inline worked. Thanks!

Comment: @user1479670 glad I helped you. Please, upvote and accept my answer